# Script produces some unintelligible text while writing to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying to write some data to a csv file extracting from some html elements. The thing is when I write the data in an excel file I can see the text in that file the way I see it in that site. However, things go wrong when I write the data to a csv file. I see some unintelligible text instead of the one I'm after.

Html elements within which the data are:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="text-default text-darker no-margin font-180 font-bold">
        شركة الوطنية            </h1>
    <h2 class="text-default font-100 no-margin vertical-offset-5">
    </h2>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
شركة الوطنية
```

When I try like:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wb = Workbook()
wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])
ws = wb.create_sheet("experimental")
ws.append(['name'])
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,"lxml")
name = soup.select_one("h1").get_text(strip=True)
ws.append([name])
wb.save("document.xlsx")
```

It produces an excel file in which the text looks like [as expected]:

[image]

However, when I try like:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("demo.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['name'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("h1").get_text(strip=True)
    writer.writerow([name])
```

It produces a csv file where the text looks horrible:

[image]

How can I write the exact text to a csv file?

Comment: Are you sure the encoding of your text is UTF-8? As is, you are telling Python that the content you are writing to the CSV file is formatted using UTF-8 character encoding. As such, it is writing it as UTF-8. This might be the source of your problem!

Comment: That surely is the wrong encoding. What would be the right approach here @alex_bits? Thanks.

Comment: Try maybe with UTF-16? That might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have suspected the issue here is with your encoding and excels understanding of it. Instead of `utf-8` you should use `utf-8-sig`

```py
import csv
text = "شركة الوطنية"
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([text])
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: A quick little question - how do I figure that which encoding I should stick to for any text? Thanks.

Comment: Encoding is a whole world within its self and it will really depend / come down to your preference or what the upstream or down stream process is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @alex_bits said I would change the UTF version to UTF-16 like below:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("demo.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-16") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['name'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("h1").get_text(strip=True)
    writer.writerow([name])
```